# How to center linear layout inside maps fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, centering

I have map's fragment, and a linear layout inside it.

I've tried: `android:gravity="center"` but it didn't work.

I've also searched in the xml for keyword of "layout" and "center" and didn't find suitable solution.

How can I solve it?

This is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    tools:context="com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap.FlightActivityUser">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map_flight_user"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flight_user_toolbar"
        tools:context="com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap.FlightActivityUser" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ratingLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="How was your flight?"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: whats the present output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gravity property affects to the content inside the layout, to align the layout itself you should use layout_gravity

Comment: Thanks it works. I didn't find this options before whille trying to write layout_ and autofill it... just the full string caused it to compile